# Return collection instead of relationship in Eloquent Model

Tags: php, laravel, collections, eloquent, relation

In my Model, I have a collection and I am trying to return it in my model, instead of relationship object.

So that I can call, `$user->items` and get that collection.

In the model, the function looks like:

```
class User extends Model {

 public function channelsAttribute() {
     $name = Company::where('id', $this->id)->first()
     $items = Item::where('company_id', $name)->get();

     return $items;
 } 
}
```

> Relationship method must return an object of type Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Relation

As it goes 2 ways, I couldn't find a way to use relationship; however `$items` returns collection of values.

What should I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not calling the method correctly, instead of

```
function channelsAttribute()
```

you need to do

```
function getChannelsAttribute()
```